# Make a View in oracle with Parameters

Tags: oracle, view

I want to make a view in Oracle in which I am required to give `student_ID` as parameter and it will extract `student_name` from `student` table.
I have no experience in views and no experience with Oracle.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504

Comment: Views cannot be parameterised in the sense that I think you mean. If you want to pass specific arguments to a query, you would have to rely on Oracle's programmability: For example, your view could reference functions in a package, which return some value and can be set through the package's interface... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024696

Comment: @Xophmeister with parameters, i meant the arguments that we can pass, just like we pass arguments to stored procedures. isn't that possible in oracle?

Comment: @AtifImtiaz Nope, not directly.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  student_id int,
  student_name varchar2(100),
  student_address varchar2(255),
  student_email varchar2(100)
);
```

Create a view with just id and name fields:

```
CREATE VIEW VSTUDENT AS
SELECT student_id, student_name
FROM STUDENT;
```

You can then:

```
SELECT student_name
FROM VSTUDENT
WHERE student_id=123;
```

Creating the view with only the student_id (query field) and student_name (required field) protects all the other student data from those who do not have access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
  SELECT student_name, student_grades, more columns...
   FROM student_table
  WHERE student_id = 20
 /
```